# Using gp_segment_id as the partition column to get data from greenplum in parallel

Tags: greenplum

Can I use multiple parallel queries with condition by gp_segment_id to select data from greenplum table in parallel?
What are the disadvantages of this method? Will I get any problems with the consistency of the result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. gp_segment_id will behave like normal column. only thing is it is hidden.

```
gpadmin=# select gp_segment_id,* from test1;
 gp_segment_id | a
---------------+---
            20 | 3
            39 | 2
            34 | 1
(3 rows)
gpadmin=# select gp_segment_id,* from test2;
 gp_segment_id | a
---------------+---
            20 | 3
            25 | 4
            39 | 2
            34 | 1
(4 rows)
gpadmin=# select * from test1 p join test2 q on p.gp_segment_id=q.gp_segment_id;
 a | a
---+---
 2 | 2
 1 | 1
 3 | 3
(3 rows)
gpadmin=#
```

You can use gp_segment_id in joins, where conditions etc. just ensure that parallel query combination is not causing resource skew.